# How to read stream video from IP cam

Tags: html, video, video-streaming

I am trying to read the streaming from a Network IP Camera.

I can connect to the IP Camera (web server) by **proprietary** web interface and I can watch the video (h.264 format), but I need to **read the video stream and put it in a web page** that I am developing.

How can I read only the stream video ?
I think I have to authenticate in some way before read the video stream, right ? (and how ?)
Do exist some particular camera that allow me to read easily the video stream ?
Is there some plugin, applet or something that I can use in my html page ?

I know: to many question :) you can suggest me some web page that can help me.

Thank you,
Alessandro

Answer (score 2, accepted):

hej allesandro,

only streaming the h.264 video data looks like a task for RTSP. There are some HTML-plugins for websites which can start a RTSP stream. Either you use one of them or you simply program your own plugin for your website. live555 is a powerful library for RTP and RTSP streaming. Try to find out if your server supports RTSP...

greetings,

jens.